# jQuery - use variable as function name

Tags: jquery

In Jquery i'd like to disable any plugin I want by changing a variable name. However the following code doesnt work

```
function disablePlugin(functionName) {
    $('#divID').functionName('disable')
}

disablePlugin('sortable');
```

any ideas about how I manage to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is how you would do that:

```
function disablePlugin(functionName) {
  $('#divID')[functionName]('disable')
}

disablePlugin('sortable');
```

This works because `someObject.foo` is the same thing as `someObject['foo']`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has worked like charm for me. Bunch of thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

To invoke the function passed in as a string, you could do

```
function disablePlugin(functionName) {
    $('#divID')[functionName]('disable')
}

disablePlugin('sortable');
```