# Jquery check if var is a function and then call it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable name that I pass into a plugin, but the variable is actually a function. 
I use jquery $.isFunction to check if it is a function, and if it is, it should execute the function.

But I can't seem to make it work, I put some examples in jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6U9/8/

But here is a sample code:

**HTML**

```
<a class="one" href="#">click</a><br />
<a class="two" href="#">click</a><br />
<a class="three" href="#">click</a><br />
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

help = function(var1) {
    alert(var1);
}

function help2(var1) {
    alert(var1);
}


$('a.one').click(function() {
    var functionName = "help";
    if ($.isFunction([functionName])) {[functionName]("hello");
    } else {
        alert("not a function");
    }

    return false;
});

$('a.two').click(function() {
    var functionName = "help";

    if ($.isFunction(functionName)) {
        functionName("hello");
    } else {
        alert("not a function");
    }
    return false;
});

$('a.three').click(function() {
    var functionName = "help2";

    if ($.isFunction(functionName)) {
        functionName("hello");
    } else {
        alert("not a function");
    }
    return false;
});

$('a.four').click(function() {
    var functionName = "help2";

    if ($.isFunction([functionName])) {[functionName]("hello");
    } else {
        alert("not a function");
    }
    return false;
});

});​
```

As you can see, I tired a bunch of things, but all the wrong ones probably...
I inspired some of them from: [jQuery - use variable as function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604113/jquery-use-variable-as-function-name)

**Overall**
I'm passing a variable that has the same name as a function, using jquery to check if it is a function, if it is, it should execute the function.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `[functionName]` is always an array, not a function. And `functionName` is also not a function, it's a string. `$.isFunction` does not test whether a function with such a name exists, it really tests whether the value you pass to it is a function. The way you set up your code you cannot actually access those two functions by a string containing their names.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks (I do get confused with this). Is there any solution?

Comment: Is this just a simplified example? Because here you could just call `help` and `help2` directly. You mentioned a plugin, so whether a solution exist *might* depend on how the plugin works.

Comment: @FelixKling - Let's hope that `help = function...` meant to be `var help`, because you can call it: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jSvPu/ Probably not recommended...

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Yeah, I assumed that actually. But even if not, `help2` is local, so I am still at least 50% right ;) :D

Comment: @FelixKling - Yes it is a very simplified. It s basically just a plugin I created, where when you call it, you need to define a function. The plugin uses an $.ajax and I define the function onComplete from my plugin. Hope it's clear.

Comment: So, `$.isFunction` will work if the user passes a function to your plugin, e.g. `$.myPlugin(function() {...});`. Your mistake was that used a string with a function name instead of the function itself. Don't make it unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are wanting to call a function by a string of its name just use `window`.

```
var functionName = "help";
if ($.isFunction(window[functionName])) {
    window[functionName]("hello");
} else {
    alert("not a function");
}
```

Comment: what if it's not global? In a way that the function isn't in the window object.

Comment: In that case replace 'window' for the name of the object where your function is. The same code applies.

Comment: @Nelson: So... how would access `help2` in this case?

Comment: @FelixKling Nesting functions like `help2` really is not a good practice to begin with.

Comment: It's more a matter of my opinion and personal experiences with doing it, but read this - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/137495/should-i-nest-functions-in-languages-that-allow-me-to-do-that-or-should-i-rather#answer-137496

Answer (score 1):

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6U9/17/) for the working example.

Example have only one link working. make other links similarly.

**Edit: after first comment**

**HTML**

```
<a class="one" href="#">click</a><br />
```

**JS**

```
var help = function(var1) {
    alert(var1);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.one').click(function() {
        var functionName = help;
        if ($.isFunction(functionName)) {
            functionName('test');
        } else {
            alert("not a function");
        }

        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Please add the code to your answer and explain it. If the link becomes unavailable for whatever reason, then your answer is useless.

Comment: @FelixKling Good point. Added code in the answer and keep that in mind for future Q/A

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to invoke functions that are defined in the window/global scope, such as the function `help`:

```
if ($.isFunction(window[functionName])) {
  window[functionName]("hello");
}
```

`help2`, on the other hand, is **not** accessible this way since you are defining it in a closure. A possibile solution is to define the function *outside* of the `.ready()` handler. Then, you can use `window[functionName]` to call it:

```
var namespace = {
  help: function (var1) {
    alert(var1);
  },

  help2: function (var1) {
    alert(var1);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var functionName = "help";
  if ($.isFunction(namespace[functionName])) {
    namespace[functionName]("hello");
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hwaaB/)**.